# How to create an archetype without the archetype-plugins default parameters?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to create an archetype that doesn't use some of the standard maven-archetype-plugin parameters like `groupId` or `package`.

How do I configure this?

I haven't found information on this on the [archetype doumentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html) and on the [documentation of the metadata](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html).

Comment: Just curious - what do you want to do that?

Comment: @gtonic - I would like to create an archetype for my personal projects. The groupId there is always fixed, so I don't want to specify that every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a way too, and since I don't know if you work with the command line or with some GUI, I share my workaround for the command line way, when you use generate just add :

`-Dpackage=- -DgroupId=-`

If they aren't used in your configuration, you won't have any problem and you don't have to prompt something in the InteractiveMode.